# Array with iferror and regexmatch?

Tags: google-sheets

In cell N4 I have lots of text. The following formula works well with letting me know if certain keywords such as finance and tech appear in the cell.

```
=iferror({REGEXEXTRACT(N4,"Finance|finance|FINANCE"),REGEXEXTRACT(N4,"Fintech|fintech|FINTECH"),REGEXEXTRACT(N4,"tech|technology|TECH|TECHNOLOGY")})
```

I want to repeat the formula to see if the same keywords appear in other cells in the column, i.e n5 through n50.

I tried

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror({REGEXEXTRACT(N4:n50,"Finance|finance|FINANCE"),REGEXEXTRACT(N4:n50,"Fintech|fintech|FINTECH"),REGEXEXTRACT(N4:n50,"tech|technology|TECH|TECHNOLOGY")})
```

but my Google sheet freezes

I also tried

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror({REGEXEXTRACT(N4:n,"Finance|finance|FINANCE"),REGEXEXTRACT(N4:n,"Fintech|fintech|FINTECH"),REGEXEXTRACT(N4:n,"tech|technology|TECH|TECHNOLOGY")})
```

but that didn't work either.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(N4:N50), 
"finance|fintech|tech|technology")))
```

Comment: Thank you. I think my combination of upper case and lower case N was causing the formula to freeze.